# Filtrar por fecha en un ListView de Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

Tengo un proyecto en el cual necesito filtrar elementos por `fecha_separacion`, por defecto inicia en la fecha actual pero necesito cambiar esa fecha por medio de un formulario.

Este es mi modelo (`models.py`):

```
class Agenda(MarcadorTiempo):
    # otros campos
    fecha_separacion = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Fecha de Separación')
```

Y este es mi Form:

```
class FechaForm(forms.Form):
    fecha = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

Esta es mi view (`views.py`):

```
class AgendaGeneralListView(ListView):

    model = Agenda
    paginate_by = 100
    template_name = 'agendas/agenda_general/agenda_general.html'
    context_object_name = 'agendas'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = FechaForm
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(AgendaGeneralListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(fecha_separacion=date.today())
```

Como pueden ver, actualmente estoy filtrando por la fecha actual, pero quisiera poder cambiar esto por la fecha que envíe por el formulario.

Debo enviar el `request` como argumento al método `get_queryset` o de que forma puedo hacer esto?

Este es el template:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="widget-body">
            <div class="widget-main">
                <label for="id-date-picker-1">Fecha De Agenda</label>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-11">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control date-picker" name="fecha" id="id-date-picker-1" type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar bigger-110"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="widget-body">
            <div class="widget-main">
                <button type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-filter bigger-120"></i>Filtrar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo resolví sobre escribiendo el método `get_queryset` de la siguiente forma

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(AgendaGeneralListView, self).get_queryset()
        fecha = date.today()
        if self.request.GET.get('fecha'):
            from datetime import datetime
            fecha_str = self.request.GET.get('fecha')
            fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha_str, '%d-%m-%Y')
        return queryset.filter(fecha_separacion=fecha)
```